# Angular Inline-Editing Component

Tags: angular, angular-input

i'm searching an Component/Plugin/Way for inline-editing in Angular like Jira. I have recorded a sample gif [Sample GIF:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIWOQ.gif)

Does have anybody a component like this? I will be happy to hear your suggestions:) Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Fanavity, Welcome to Stackoverflow.
Please have look at this example: [Inline editing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inline-edit?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit-input%2Fedit-input.component.html)

Comment: Thats cool, but only for text-input. But i need dropdown, texteditor, too.

Comment: Please have look at this example as well. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grid-edit-with-dropdown). As of now its under Grid. Atleast you have a look at logic and make use of directive.

Comment: I Have found this one: https://github.com/ngneat/edit-in-place i think its very nice. I only search a method to hover the input to show the user that he can click into it.

Comment: Looks great, Since this library is build in ```Angular11``` So please check the compatibility with your application. All the Best :)